# how to dynamically require field in flow builder using formula

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow

### Question

Is it possible to make a field required dynamically depending on another field's selected value?

### Acceptance Criteria

If a user selects "*Sales*" from the department dropdown menu, make the field "*department number*" required

**Attempted but failed**
I tried creating a formula for the selected value and I placed the formula variable in the required field of "department number" but it did not do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two main approaches come to mind:

1) Set up [conditional visibility](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screen_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5)

- Including two instances of the second input component in the screen
- Making one required, and the other optional
- Setting up conditional visibility on them so that only one is displayed at a time (based on whether or not it should be required)
- You could use decision and assignment elements after the screen to store the selected value in a variable so you don't have to duplicate your create/update/get elements

2) [Validate users’ inputs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screen_validate.htm&type=5) with flow formulas

- Functionality only available on certain input components (eg. Text)
- Has been quite buggy in my experience
- If the user leaves the field blank, and the field is not required, the flow doesn’t validate.

Other approaches include setting up a decision element to check value of second field and returning to screen + displaying error if it's blank, or building a LWC for the two fields in question and embedding it in the screen. The first two are much better options though.

Comment: Great, your first suggestion helped me achieve my goal. Thank you very much.